# What is the standard COM HRESULT for an obsolete function?

Tags: c++, com, vb6

I am working on a VB6 project. There are a few methods I want to make obsolete. After removing the method body, the idea is to raise a standard COM error, e.g.

```
Err.Raise E_NOTIMPL
```

In this case, I am using the standard "Method not implemented" error, but that isn't really the right message I want returned.

Any ideas?

Comment: Given there's nothing apparently relevant [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eldar/archive/2007/04/03/a-lot-of-hresult-codes.aspx), I'd just go with what you've got.

Comment: If removing obsolete methods doesn't hurt, and is not intended to produce an error, you could also return S_FALSE. Also, bear in mind, that you probably need to declare a new interface without obsolete methods, instead of cutting down the methods internals.

Comment: You don't have a lot of choice, there are very few standard HRESULTs to choose from.  Make it self-documenting, include at least the Description argument.

Comment: @Stan - this is more intended to throw up errors in integration testing, so an error description is pretty important to me. In any case, VB6 doesn't allow you to directly return an HRESULT.

Comment: @Hans Passant - yes, it is increasingly more evident that standard errors are a bit thin on the ground. And yes, I am going to supply a Description to make it more obvious what I am trying to do.

Comment: If the objective is to be obvious in integration testing, remove the function altogether, and change the CLSID and IID.

Comment: You cannot "return" `S_FALSE` with `Err.Raise` in VB6. `E_NOTIMPL` works and most of the other error `HRESULT`s too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the methods still work, but are deprecated, leave them in, and mark them as hidden and nonbrowsable in the IDL, putting in appropriate comments in the helpstring. This hides them from the developer.

If they don't work any more, then in theory you need a new CLSID as you have broken the contract.

If they don't work any more, *but no client was ever actually using them*, then you can use E_NOTIMPL - that would be appropriate. (Also mark them hidden and add a helpstring explaining.)

But note that if a caller **is** calling the method, they are just as broken whether you return E_NOTIMPL or create a new clsid and make them recompile.

Comment: I know where you are going here, but I would query whether the COM contract is about runtime behaviour. I thought the contract was more to do with the layout of the VTable. If you get the latter wrong, you are on the way to Access Violation city, whilst the former at least tells you why things have gone wrong, before your process blows up.

Comment: The process is just as dead either way. Arguably the Access Violation is better because if they have `On Error Resume Next` they may not even notice and who knows what data corruption may occur? Bottom line: If you have got active clients using the function, either don't remove the function or make sure they **know** the new version is incompatible - by changing the CLSID and IID.